# Lambda/Action with more than one statement in C#. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, lambda

Currently I have this:

```
foreach (Expression e in arguments)
{
    e.shouldBePushedToStack = true;
    scope.addChild(e);
}
```

And I wonder if I could do something like this: (not actual legal code)

```
arguments.ForEach( e => e.shouldBePushedToStack = true, 
                        scope.addChild(e));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do multi-line lambdas like so:

```
arguments.ForEach( e => {
    e.shouldBePushedToStack = true;
    scope.addChild(e));
});
```

Note that in order to return a value from a multiline lambda, you must use the `return` keywork. As a trivial example:

```
arguments.Select( e => {
    if (e.shouldBePushedToStack) {
        return "foo";
    } else {
        return "baz";
    }
});
```

However, given that your code has side-effects (modifying `e`, and appending to an external list), it may be more clear to explicitly use a `foreach` loop and avoid LINQ, since (as far as I know), LINQ implies you're doing functional-style transformations, which implies there are no side-effects from running the operation.

Comment: I very much agree with your last statement. More developers need to be aware of where to draw the line and stop refactoring every `foreach` loop with Linq.

Answer (score 2):

```
arguments.ForEach(e =>
{
    e.shouldBePushedToStack = true;
    scope.addChild(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - notice `{ }` wrapping multiple statements.

```
 arguments.ForEach( e => {
                    e.shouldBePushedToStack = true, 
                    scope.addChild(e);
       });
```

In some cases you may need to return value - simply add `return`:

```
 arguments.Where( e => {
                    bool result = true; 
                    // some code here....
                    return result;
       });
```